# What to use to replay messages in ActiveMQ and Why?

Tags: java, apache, jms, activemq-classic, middleware

My use case needs me to replay messages sent on one destination to another (one or more).

There can be four possible combinations :

> 1. Topic -> Topic (CompositeTopic)
> 2. Topic -> Queue (CompositeTopic, VirtualTopic)
> 3. Queue -> Topic (CompositeQueue, MirroredQueue)
> 4. Queue -> Queue (CompositeQueue)

Are there other ways to replay messages other then listed one?

***Which one to use in case of Topic -> Queue CompositeTopic or VirtualTopic ? When and Why ?***

***Which one to use in case of Queue -> Topic CompositeQueue, MirroredQueue ? When and Why***

There are different features provided for same thing so there has to be some subtle differences which am unable to find. Can someone share any info on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You list the basic "one to many" options you have.

1. - Virtual Topics are automatic, out of the box, topic->queue subscriptions. They work really well and solve a few problems that regular topics/durable subscriptions cannot solve. Virtual topic are, however, based on naming conventions, so you need to stick to whatever convention you configure - which can be a drawback in some cases.
   - If you feel you need more dynamic ways to control which queues that should subscribe to a topic, then simply revert to a composite.
2. - Mirrored Queues are not really meant to be used as re-routing. It's more an admin tool to wire tap all queues to monitor what messages are passing through the broker.
   - A composite queue is the easiest way to handle one to many destinations.

However, ActiveMQ comes [bundled](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) with [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/). If you want to have a richer set of options where to dispatch the message, you could simply send it to queue (or topic) which you have a Camel route listen to and then dispatch it to whom it may concern.

Comment: are there any performance difference between VirtualTopic and Composite topic when it comes to forward message from topic to queue only if I do not care about naming. I can not use camel right now, so need basic options only.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know of any performance differences. My gut feeling is that you should not worry too much about it. Measure your scenario if you feel it's % differences in performance is important. Virtual topics is the encouraged solution to subscribe a topic via queues.